# Include Rstudio script in i OS swift project

Tags: ios, r, swift, xcode

I am building an application in swift for iOS. I have also built a project in RStudio that generates complex graphs from a user's raw data. I would like to embed these graphs into my iOS application.

Comment: So what is the **specifics* of your issue?

Comment: What are the things that have you tried? can you put some of the code and libraries that you used?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I know your question is general, but it is a worthy one because theres not a lot of other information on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @rdk No I didn't find a solution but after asking about the best conclusion I came to is to use https://shiny.rstudio.com/ Shiny which packages my R scripts as a web app then create an API endpoint to communicate that web app with my iOS application. You would have to take your own security precautions. Another option is to convert your R scripts into Python (as it has a similar library) and embed python in your xcode project.